# How to remove devexpress right-click menu from my gridview?

Tags: .net, gridview, menu, devexpress, right-click

[image]

I dont want this menu. How to remove it? Which property should I use?

Comment: Please try it with some textBox (textBox.Properties.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip ();) and let me know.
and please what is your devexpress version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu from your picture actually is editor's context menu. The editor is created when you starting to edit the cell. Also this menu you can see only from `TextEdit` and its descendants. `TextEdit` itself is container which holds the `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` descendant. By default, `TextEdit` prevents  `TextBox` context menu and shows its own. But, if the value of `TextEdit.ContextMenu` or `TextEdit.ContextMenuStrip` properties are not null, then menu of this properties are showing instead of default menu. So, technically, if you create empty `ContextMenu` or `ContextMenuStrip` and update the properties by this menus, then the are no menu will be shown.

You can use [`GridView.ActiveEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ActiveEditortopic) property to get the current editor and you can use [`GridView.ShownEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event to update the current editor context menu.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var view = (GridView)sender;
    var editor = view.ActiveEditor as TextEdit;

    if (editor == null)
        return;

    editor.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get an editor used in column by using the [GridColumn.RealColumnEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_RealColumnEdittopic) property. Cast it to RepositoryItemTextEdit and than handle its [RepositoryItemTextEdit.BeforeShowMenu](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdit_BeforeShowMenutopic) event. Clear all items in the menu in the event handler. This will prevent the menu from being shown.

```
RepositoryItemTextEdit rep = gridView1.Columns["your field name"].RealColumnEdit as RepositoryItemTextEdit;
rep.BeforeShowMenu += rep_BeforeShowMenu;

void rep_BeforeShowMenu(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BeforeShowMenuEventArgs e) {
    e.Menu.Items.Clear();
}
```

**Edited:**
If you need to disable that menu for all columns and as a result all cells, you can traverse through all columns instead of getting a single one:

```
foreach(var col in gridView1.Columns) {
    RepositoryItemTextEdit rep = col.RealColumnEdit as RepositoryItemTextEdit;
    rep.BeforeShowMenu += rep_BeforeShowMenu;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with columns. This menu pops up when I click all the cells of a row.

Comment: @nrtn93 Does not your cell belong to a column? If so, where is it?

Comment: When I click any cells, I see this popup menu.

Comment: @nrtn93 Obviously those cells are in columns. Columns have repository items that control what editor will be created for a cell.

Comment: Should ı write this code for every column one by one?

Comment: Another solution worked. It is ok now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that there are can be other `RepositoryItem` descendants, so `col.RealColumnEdit as RepositoryItemTextEdit` can return `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q313321

To hide the column menu set the `GridView.OptionsMenu.EnableColumnMenu` property to `false`.

Comment: @nrtn93 It's better for you to show your actual attempt to do it. Then someone could point you to the possible error.

Answer (score 0):

The image that you showed is a general contextMenu (not column menu) and by default it displays itself. If you do not want to appear,You have to assign an empty context menu.

```
gridControl.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip ();
...
textBox.Properties.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip ();
```